# Mobile Broadband do not work with Thinkpad T440p on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: networking, 13.10, thinkpad, mobile-broadband, wwan

I have a new Lenovo T440p with built in Mobile Broadband a Lenovo N5321gw (I'm guessing its a rebranded Ericsson H5321gw).

Ubuntu detects it fine and I can configure it and give the pin-code. But as soon as I press connect it try to connect and then fails with this in the log:

```
Jan 21 19:13:36 maximus kernel: [   54.432298] usb 3-10: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
Jan 21 19:13:36 maximus kernel: [   54.449019] usb 3-10: New USB device found, idVendor=0bdb, idProduct=193f
Jan 21 19:13:36 maximus kernel: [   54.449022] usb 3-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
Jan 21 19:13:36 maximus kernel: [   54.449024] usb 3-10: Product: N5321 gw
Jan 21 19:13:36 maximus kernel: [   54.449025] usb 3-10: Manufacturer: Lenovo
Jan 21 19:13:36 maximus kernel: [   54.449027] usb 3-10: SerialNumber: 44********
Jan 21 19:13:36 maximus pppd[2782]: Exit.

--- Pressing connect here ---

Jan 21 19:14:26 maximus kernel: [  104.463741] usbhid 3-10:1.0: can't add hid device: -110
Jan 21 19:14:26 maximus kernel: [  104.463772] usbhid: probe of 3-10:1.0 failed with error -110
Jan 21 19:14:26 maximus kernel: [  104.463895] usb 3-10: USB disconnect, device number 8
Jan 21 19:14:26 maximus kernel: [  104.703794] usb 3-10: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
Jan 21 19:14:26 maximus kernel: [  104.722786] usb 3-10: New USB device found, idVendor=0bdb, idProduct=193e
Jan 21 19:14:26 maximus kernel: [  104.722800] usb 3-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jan 21 19:14:26 maximus kernel: [  104.722808] usb 3-10: Product: N5321 gw
Jan 21 19:14:26 maximus kernel: [  104.722815] usb 3-10: Manufacturer: Lenovo
Jan 21 19:14:26 maximus kernel: [  104.722821] usb 3-10: SerialNumber: 44************
Jan 21 19:14:26 maximus kernel: [  104.756813] cdc_acm 3-10:1.1: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
Jan 21 19:14:26 maximus kernel: [  104.760797] cdc_acm 3-10:1.3: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
Jan 21 19:14:26 maximus kernel: [  104.768804] cdc_wdm 3-10:1.5: cdc-wdm1: USB WDM device
Jan 21 19:14:26 maximus kernel: [  104.796140] cdc_mbim 3-10:1.6: cdc-wdm2: USB WDM device
Jan 21 19:14:26 maximus kernel: [  104.796491] cdc_mbim 3-10:1.6 wwan0: register 'cdc_mbim' at usb-0000:00:14.0-10, CDC MBIM, ce:bc:1e:4a:d7:9f
Jan 21 19:14:26 maximus kernel: [  104.797298] cdc_wdm 3-10:1.8: cdc-wdm3: USB WDM device
Jan 21 19:14:26 maximus kernel: [  104.797767] cdc_acm 3-10:1.9: ttyACM2: USB ACM device
Jan 21 19:14:26 maximus mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 9: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-10"
Jan 21 19:14:26 maximus mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 9 was not an MTP device
Jan 21 19:14:26 maximus NetworkManager[902]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-10/3-10:1.6/net/wwan0, iface: wwan0)
Jan 21 19:14:26 maximus NetworkManager[902]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-10/3-10:1.6/net/wwan0, iface: wwan0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Jan 21 19:14:26 maximus modem-manager[846]: <info>  (ttyACM1) opening serial port...
Jan 21 19:14:26 maximus modem-manager[846]: <info>  (ttyACM0) opening serial port...
Jan 21 19:14:26 maximus modem-manager[846]: <info>  (ttyACM2) opening serial port...
Jan 21 19:14:30 maximus modem-manager[846]: <info>  (ttyACM1) closing serial port...
Jan 21 19:14:30 maximus modem-manager[846]: <info>  (ttyACM1) serial port closed
Jan 21 19:14:30 maximus modem-manager[846]: <info>  (Generic): GSM modem /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-10 claimed port ttyACM1
Jan 21 19:14:30 maximus modem-manager[846]: <info>  (ttyACM0) closing serial port...
Jan 21 19:14:30 maximus modem-manager[846]: <info>  (ttyACM0) serial port closed
Jan 21 19:14:30 maximus modem-manager[846]: <info>  (Generic): GSM modem /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-10 claimed port ttyACM0
Jan 21 19:14:30 maximus modem-manager[846]: <info>  (ttyACM2) closing serial port...
Jan 21 19:14:30 maximus modem-manager[846]: <info>  (ttyACM2) serial port closed
Jan 21 19:14:30 maximus modem-manager[846]: <info>  (Generic): GSM modem /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-10 claimed port ttyACM2
Jan 21 19:14:30 maximus modem-manager[846]: <info>  (ttyACM0) opening serial port...
Jan 21 19:14:30 maximus NetworkManager[902]: <warn> (ttyACM0): failed to look up interface index
Jan 21 19:14:30 maximus NetworkManager[902]: <info> WWAN now disabled by management service
Jan 21 19:14:30 maximus NetworkManager[902]: <info> (ttyACM0): new GSM/UMTS device (driver: 'cdc_acm' ifindex: 0)
Jan 21 19:14:30 maximus NetworkManager[902]: <info> (ttyACM0): exported as /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
Jan 21 19:14:30 maximus NetworkManager[902]: <info> (ttyACM0): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Jan 21 19:14:30 maximus NetworkManager[902]: <info> (ttyACM0): deactivating device (reason 'managed') [2]
Jan 21 19:14:30 maximus NetworkManager[902]: <info> (ttyACM0): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none') [20 30 0]
Jan 21 19:14:33 maximus modem-manager[846]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager/Modems/1: unlock no longer required
Jan 21 19:14:33 maximus modem-manager[846]: <info>  (ttyACM0) closing serial port...
Jan 21 19:14:33 maximus modem-manager[846]: <info>  (ttyACM0) serial port closed
Jan 21 19:14:56 maximus NetworkManager[902]: <info> Activation (ttyACM0) starting connection 'Telia Telia 3G 1'
Jan 21 19:14:56 maximus NetworkManager[902]: <info> (ttyACM0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jan 21 19:14:56 maximus NetworkManager[902]: <info> Activation (ttyACM0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Jan 21 19:14:56 maximus NetworkManager[902]: <info> Activation (ttyACM0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Jan 21 19:14:56 maximus NetworkManager[902]: <info> Activation (ttyACM0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Jan 21 19:14:56 maximus modem-manager[846]: <info>  (ttyACM0) opening serial port...
Jan 21 19:14:56 maximus whoopsie[1132]: offline
Jan 21 19:14:56 maximus modem-manager[846]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager/Modems/1: state changed (disabled -> enabling)
Jan 21 19:14:56 maximus modem-manager[846]: <info>  (ttyACM1) opening serial port...
Jan 21 19:14:56 maximus modem-manager[846]: <info>  (ttyACM0): using PDU mode for SMS
Jan 21 19:14:56 maximus modem-manager[846]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager/Modems/1: state changed (enabling -> enabled)
Jan 21 19:14:56 maximus NetworkManager[902]: <info> WWAN now enabled by management service
Jan 21 19:14:56 maximus modem-manager[846]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager/Modems/1: state changed (enabled -> registered)
Jan 21 19:14:57 maximus modem-manager[846]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager/Modems/1: state changed (registered -> connecting)
Jan 21 19:14:58 maximus modem-manager[846]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager/Modems/1: state changed (connecting -> connected)
Jan 21 19:14:58 maximus NetworkManager[902]: <info> Activation (ttyACM0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Jan 21 19:14:58 maximus NetworkManager[902]: <info> Activation (ttyACM0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Jan 21 19:14:58 maximus NetworkManager[902]: <info> (ttyACM0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jan 21 19:14:58 maximus NetworkManager[902]: <info> Activation (ttyACM0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
```

After this I need to reboot the computer to enable it again.

So I downloaded modem-manager-gui and looked around in there. It also detect the mobile boradband, I can also enable it and scan for networks it works fine. It detects the right provider. I can also send SMS and I do receive them. The SIM-card have been successfully used in another computer before.

```
$> for n in `ls /sys/class/*/*{ACM,wdm}*/device/interface`;do echo $(echo $n|awk -F '/' '{print $5}') : $(cat $n);done
ttyACM0 : N5321 gw Mobile Broadband Modem
ttyACM1 : N5321 gw Mobile Broadband Data Modem
ttyACM2 : N5321 gw Mobile Broadband GPS Port
cdc-wdm1 : N5321 gw Mobile Broadband Device Management
cdc-wdm2 : N5321 gw Mobile Broadband USIM Port
cdc-wdm3 : Ericsson N5321 gw
```

Anyone know what is wrong?

/BR Erik

Answer (score 3):

These modules implement both the NCM and MBIM protocols in a single function, meaning that the kernel has to make a choice on behalf of the user because the choice is made while selecting the appropriate driver. This is unfortunate because the kernel has no knowledge about neither userspace application support nor user preferences.  The problem in your case is that MBIM was selected by the kernel, but isn't yet supported by the ModemManager version you have.

The long term solution would be a newer ModemManager with proper MBIM support.  But until that is available in Ubuntu, you can tell the kernel to make a different choice. The default preference can be temporarily overridden by doing

```
 echo N >/sys/module/cdc_ncm/parameters/prefer_mbim
```

or more permanently changed by creating e.g. a */etc/modprobe.d/ncm.conf* file with a line like this:

```
 options cdc_ncm prefer_mbim=N
```

Note that this new preference will only take effect on the next driver probe, so you will have to "unplug" and replug the modem to make it effective.  And as your modem is built-in, that probably means using rfkill. Or just create the file and unload/reload the drivers.  Or reboot if you find that easiest.  Be aware the temporary solution given above will only work with the rfkill based method.

The above should only be considered a temporary workaround. There are good reasons why you would want to use MBIM for mobile broadband devices in the future, as soon as the ModemManager support is in place. The NCM interface management is based on a few vendor specific AT commands. MBIM provides a standardized and much more complete 3G/LTE modem management protocol.